# jQuery / JS get the scrollbar height of an textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, scrollbar

I've got a textarea with a fixed height. When the user types text into the textarea a scrollbar will show up after the user typed some text in it.

How can I get the scrollbar height using jQuery or plain JavaScript? I've been searching for this for hours, but couldn't find anything. I can't just insert a div and get the scrollbar height via the div offset because a textarea is not allowed to have child elements.

Please don't give me a link to a jQuery Plug-In that does the job. I want to learn something.

Comment: What browser? FF 4.0, FF 3.6, IE.  TextAreas are rendered slightly different in each browser.

Comment: Chrome 10 and FF4. I've made sure the textarea has a scrollbar! (not that much height but lots of text in the textarea)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
textarea.scrollHeight
```

returns an integer (pixels)

Comment: `alert($('textarea:first').scrollHeight);` returns undefined. The selector works fine (I tried it with .css) and jQuery is included.

Comment: `scrollHeight` is an attribute of the DOM element. It doesn't exist for the jQuery object. Use `.attr('scrollHeight')` or `$('textarea:first').get(0).scrollHeight`

Comment: If using jQuery 1.6 or later, use `$('textarea:first').prop('scrollHeight)` instead of `.attr('scrollHeight)`. "As of jQuery 1.6, [the .prop() method](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes… Prior to jQuery 1.6, these properties were retrievable with the .attr() method, but this was not within the scope of attr."

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each($("textarea"), function () {
    var scrollHeight = parseInt(this.scrollHeight);
    if ($("this").val() != "" && isNaN(scrollHeight) == false && scrollHeight > 0 && scrollHeight > $(this).height()) {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"));
        $(this).height(scrollHeight);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you should exclude the **upper padding** and the **lower padding** of the textarea while comparing the scrollHeight.

#### Example

```
var scrollHeight = $("#textarea_id")[0].scrollHeight;
var padding = 14; //upperpadding 7 and lower padding 7.

if($("#textarea_id")[0].height() < (scrollHeight - padding)) {
  $("#textarea_id")[0].height(scrollHeight - padding);
}
```