# can't get textarea's scrollheight when delete contents

Tags: jquery, textarea

I want to get the scrollheight of  `<textarea>`  when people changing the content.The problem is when I add the content ,I can get a growing scrollheight ，but when I delete contents,I can't get a Reduced scrollheight。And here is the code

```
$("textarea[id^='_sub_ialready_']").live("keydown keyup focus blur",
    function()
    {
        if(aobj.minHeight == 0)
        aobj.minHeight = $(this).height();
        if($(this).attr("scrollHeight") > aobj.minHeight)
        {
            if($(this).attr("scrollHeight") > aobj.maxHeight)
            {
                nheight = aobj.maxHeight;
                $(this).css("overflow-Y",'scroll');    
            }    
            else
            {
                nheight = $(this).attr("scrollHeight");
                $(this).css("overflow-Y",'hidden');    
            }
            $(this).height(nheight);
       }
    }
)
```

Comment: Could you specify your css or a little bit more of code so we can understand better what would you wanna do? Also, have you checked out any of these questions about getting scrollHeight?:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980150/jquery-js-get-the-scrollbar-height-of-an-textarea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642353/dynamically-scrolling-a-textarea
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is set height to `auto` first, like so:

```
$('#textarea').height('auto');
```

Then get the scrollHeight property:

```
var h = $('#textarea').prop('scrollHeight');
```

Answer (score 0):

What about...

```
.attr('scrollHeight')
```

**OR**

```
$('textarea:first').get(0).scrollHeight
```

**OR (returns an integer in pixels)**

```
textarea.scrollHeight
```

Comment: the problem is : when I add contents I can get a growing scrollheight,but when I delete the contents,I can't get a reducing scrollheight

Comment: @ivyandrich Hi, I got the same problem. How did you solve it?